# Access iCloud.com from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud

I noticed that in the HTML of icloud.com there are meta tags for creating a webapp on iOS devices. However it is impossible to get to just icloud.com on the iPhone, instead it redirects you to icloud.com/iphone_welcome.

Am I missing something? Or is this some future capability?

Comment: What do you want to do on iCloud.com on the iPhone that you can't do on the iPhone directly? (Edit Contact groups?)

Comment: If its not my phone, and I just quickly want to check my emails etc?

Answer (score 1):

Safari on iPhone will always be redirected to the welcome page. AFAIK there's no chance to just access www.icloud.com with Safari.
However, you can try [Google's Chrome Browser](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/chrome/id535886823?mt=8). It has an option to access a page in a desktop version. That will bring up the original iCloud page with the login dialog.